# running subprocesses in parallel with Python

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am trying to understand how can I build a parallel computing pipeline for multiple subprocesses.
As I see, each subprocess block waits for the previous code block to run, whereas I have a pipeline which does not have a dependency for the previous run, and it can be handled in parallel. I want to understand whether this is possible, and if so, a sample syntax for showing how to do that would be a great help! Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess


subprocess.run("python pipelinecode1.py".split() +
               [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.run("python pipelinecode2.py".split() +
               [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.run("python pipelinecode3.py".split() +
               [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The MCVE as-is shows zero dependency on the python-interpreter, so the most efficient step for running a set of mutualy independent tasks ( not a pipeline, where one-step-after-another *order of processing steps **"forms"** the "pipeline"* ) is GNU `parallel`:

```
$ parallel python {} run_date this_wk last_wk prev_wk ::: pipelinecode1.py \
                                                          pipelinecode2.py  \
                                                          pipelinecode3.py
```

This way you do not waste CPU / cache resources and escape from the blocking and GIL-lock re-introduced re-`[SERIAL]`-isation of the code-execution without any add-on overhead costs.

For all configurables available read respective details in `man parallel`

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax you suggest, shall I run it on cmd ? I am using Atom as editor.

Comment: @CagdasKanar yes, this is the standard GNU package, install it, if it was not installed so far, read the man-page and feel free to configure any additional tricks available to run this from terminal and enjoy the powers thereof